# How to fix the rider view, when it's only showing a grid

Tags: rendering

I am currently using blender for the first time.
When I want to see the render (F11), there is only a grid. I already checked the camera view a the lighting, but this doesn't seem to be the problem. This happens in every file I create. pls help

Louisa[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F11</kbd> is to view the render but if you've not already rendered (<kbd>F12</kbd>) you won't see anything, so first render